# Using variable with public const modifier

Tags: c++, private, public

I'd like to have a variable in my class that is `const` when accessed from `public` scope and non-`const` when accessed from a `private` or protected scope. I'd like to avoid having a getter-method that returns a const reference to the variable. I tried messing around with the `using` keyword, but no success so far. Ideally it would look something like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    using var = const m_var; // This is of course gibberish
private:
    int m_var;
}
```

I could add a public const reference member variable and let it point to the private variable, but that way my class would get 4 bytes bigger, which I would like to avoid. Would a compiler realize that and optimize out that reference?

Any other ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: "I'd like to avoid having a getter-method that returns a const reference to the variable." Why not? That's the recommended way of doing it. A reference to an object is the same as direct access to the object from a language's point of view, therefore is it the same thing

Comment: And no, C++ doesn't have something like C#'s properties

Comment: A getter-method would solve the problem, but it would also look ugly: `object.var.incrementByOne()` vs `object.getVar().incrementByOne()`. Despite the fact that the functionality is the same, it looks rather like a copy of the variable is returned and operated on, rather than the actual variable itself. I should add, that `incrementByOne()` is (for whatever reason) a `const` function.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't look like that at all. That's entirely in your mind. This "problem" is entirely artificial, and only the result of a completely arbitrary restriction you've set on your code. It's not a real problem.

Comment: It might look like this to you, if you come from another language, but that's unfortunately the only efficient way to it in C++, so C++ readers are used to it. By the way, is there any possibility you could make your `Foo` object `const` to the client code in all cases? In that case, you could expose `m_var` as a public member, make it `mutable` and change it only from your private functions. That's the only other `hack` I can think of right now

Comment: Never mind my suggestion, I think public `mutable` members are modifyable from an external scope.

Comment: If you really want to implement property-like behavior, you may go with [this solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_%28programming%29).

Comment: If it's mutable, then it can be accessed and changed from a public scope, so what's the point of doing that? In any case, the `Foo` class has other methods that aren't const, so that wouldn't really work.

Comment: I looked at the `property`-class, and even though it looks like an elegant solution it would also add a lot of overhead. If I'm having overhead anyways, I'd rather go with the public const reference to the private variable.

Comment: You might be overestimating the overhead. It's just simple inlineable functions with reads and assignments, your compiler can optimize that out.

Comment: Hm, I looked it again and I'm unsure about how exactly it would solve the problem. If I replace the variable with a property, the property is still either public or private, and can't have different constness for different scopes.

Comment: @MarcMerony You can create a `class GetProperty` that only defines the conversion operator, and not `operator=`. I agree the example on wikipedia is not great, but I'm sure you understand what I mean if you look at their example and do what I just said

Comment: @KABoissonneault But how would I then have access to the variable without constness from `private` scope? Afaik a `GetProperty` would just be similar to a regular `const` member variable (at least if the property is `const` itself. Otherwise it would be non-`const` in `public` scope, which also wouldn't solve the problem)

Comment: @MarcMerony Right, that's only assuming you use the "re-usable, templated external class" shown in the example. You can actually define `class GetProperty` inside `class Foo`, and in that case `Foo` will have access to the private member `value` of `class GetProperty`. So from `Foo`, you will do something like `this->var.value = 42`, and from outside you could read with `myFoo.var`

Comment: That makes sense. Though I wouldn't then be able to call a member function of the `var` property without retrieving the actual object/ converting it to the actual type first. I can only call functions that are defined on the `property`-class, like the assignment operator.

Comment: @MarcMerony That's what `operator T const &` is there for. It converts the property to the actual type automatically for the caller. They might get some surprise if they capture `var` with `auto`, though.

Comment: Might be able to do this with a const reference, but I have never tried. I will.

Comment: "Would a compiler realize that and optimize out that reference?" It might, but you have no guarantee that all compilers would.

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to avoid having a getter-method that returns a const reference to the variable

I don't know why you'd like to avoid that. This sounds like exactly what you want (perhaps just returning by-value):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int getVar() const { return m_var; }
protected:
    int m_var;
};
```

If you have `protected` or `private` access to `Foo`, you can just `m_var`. If you don't, then you have a public const `getVar()` that doesn't let you modify it.

---

There's really no other way of doing this. You can't overload on access rights in the way you can have overload on `const`-qualification or ref-qualification since overload resolution happens before access checking. That prohibits you from doing something like having a `protected` and `public` overload where the `protected` overload is the better match.

You also can't add aliases for variables without introducing actual references - but at that point you're making your class bigger but you still are using different names to reference the `public` and `protected` anyway, at which point using the public accessor member function is strictly better.

Comment: The question explicitely asks for "no getter" though. You can infer from the comments that OP doesn't like the syntax/semantics of calling a getter, because you supposedly can't tell if you're dealing directly with the value or a copy. I don't agree with that, but that's another debate

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is the wrong way to do it, I'm just saying it doesn't answer the question. Obviously OP is already aware that they can use a getter, so this doesn't add anything.

Comment: @KABoissonneault I dont get whats the difference between a copy and the value itselft if the value is supposed to be const anyhow

Comment: @Barry The very reason you're here is to help me fix my problem. Why else would you post something?

Comment: @MarcMerony It seems like you already know how to solve your problem - you just want to do it in a different, specific way - but what you actually want to do doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Not doing what OP wants and not answering the question are two different things. If I said use `fno-access-checking`, that may answer OP's question but it's not really that useful, is it?

Comment: @MarcMerony Barry has reached ~615k people. I'm pretty sure *you're* not the reason he's here.

Comment: @KABoissonneault: I think Barry's answer does answer the question, and that basically, what the OP posted is an XY problem. Using a getter is good because it creates an abstraction layer, between users of the class and the actual implementation. If you need to refactor it so that the `int` won't actually exist anymore as a class member, you can give a new implementation for the getter without breaking all code that uses the getter. If client code can see the `int` member, then they can take its address also. When you use a getter, it doesn't imply that the address actually exists.

Comment: @KABoissonneault: Usually you want these things and doing some weird quasi-public `int` would be a sign of code-smell IMO. At least in C++.